# who to configure fop2 with wazo

Tags: nginx, asterisk

I installed wazo on a Debian 9 and I also installed fop2 by following the script on their official website.

when I do
`/ usr / local / fop2 / fop2_server --test`
==> Connection to manager OK!

but when testing from a web interface
==> No input file specified.

can someone tell me what to do to get access from the web

open for any suggestion.

Comment: Where is programming question here? It seams like topic for FOP2 support forum.

Comment: the question is how to get access from the web interface of fop2.
do i have to configure nginx? what can i do?

Comment: Fop 2 works with apache2. Also need open comunication port - see in config file.

Comment: to work fop2 with xivo the fop2 folder must be placed in the xivo-web-interface directory and no longer in / var / www / html / so i can't configure it with nginx or apache2